# SSH client behaviour changed since private key implementation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, apache-sshd

I've just changed our authentication methods for connecting via SSH as we're moving into production for our app, we're also in the middle of migrating to EC2@AWS.

Its been a few days now and I've started to notice a few little changes whcih seem small but none the less, causing me to make mistakes as we run through command lines.

We disabled root logins to start with and now working on a range of users, all with different keys etc.

1. We no longer get our login 'introduction' when we login. We had some pretty useful information on there which we enjoyed reviewing - Where is that stored and how do we get it back or rebuild it?
2. We cant 'tab' to autocomplete the filenames anymore. This probably saves us tens of hours a week in typing so would be nice to get this back.

Im sure theres a configuration file somewhere but the files I've reviewed give little to no clue on either of these issues.

Comment: Configure `/etc/motd` & `etc/profile` accordingly. Try [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)

Comment: To expand a bit, your issues almost certainly have nothing to do with use of SSH keys, but rather with use (via those keys) of different _userids_, which are set-up differently. For example maybe root used bash but your other user uses dash, or csh, or something else. Or 'dotfiles' like `.profile .bash_login .zshrc` (specifics vary depending on your shell(s)) may be different.